# Weird scope behavior when using templateUrl directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have having the following simplified plunker to show a problem I am having with a directive of mine:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aXW7YlpensjcYsLTGwmo?p=preview

This has a directive that uses the compile property and returns an object with pre/post functions.  The issue that I am having is that any changes I make to the scope in the pre function are not reflected in the scope that the post function gets passed in when I am using the templateUrl property on the directive.

The plunker has console logs so if you open up the console you will notice that there is a object logged and the undefined and that is logging of scope.options in the pre and post functions of the returned object within the compile property.  If you open the app.js and comment out the templateUrl definition, you get 2 logs of the same object, it is not undefined in the post anymore.  This also works when using the template property.

Is there any reason changes I make in the compile's return object pre function are not reflected in the post function scope only when the directive has templateUrl property defined?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1) The first is that `containerDir` creates isolate scope, so the controller's `testOptions` is unavailable to the `inputDir` *span* through its `options` binding and `undefined` is passed instead.

2) The second, which is more related to your question, is that the `options` manipulation uses an isolate scope binding which seems to be evaluated at various times (pre and post link).  Changes you make to the variable appear to get overwritten the next time the binding is evaluated.

In the pre-link method, the binding is evaluated to undefined (because `testOptions` is undefined due to issue #1.  That undefined value is then overwritten by some code in your pre-link.  Then, when the post-link executes, I think the bindings are evaluated again and `options` is again set to `undefined`.

I would suggest that along with fixing the first isolate scope binding issue with `containerDir`, that you use the `options` property only to retrieve the values and use another scope variable to manipulate the data so that it is not overwritten.